# CSS: how to add a down arrow for the active link

Tags: css

![enter image description here][1]I have the following CSS navigation that adds an arrow on hover.

How can add an arrow to be visible for the active  or on link? i have attached the image as well

Here is my code below

```
<style type="text/css">
#nav {
    margin-top:0;
padding: 12px 0;
margin-left: 0;
background-color: #fafafa;
color: #464646;

    -moz-box-shadow: 0 5px  5px #888;
-webkit-box-shadow: 0 5px  5px #888;
box-shadow: 0 5px 5px #888;
}

#nav li {
    list-style: none;
    display: inline;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0;
    padding: 22px;
    padding-right: 0;
    padding-left: 0;
}

#nav li a {
    font-family: Arial;
    font-style:normal;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #464646;
   padding: .7em 3em;

    border-right: 1px dashed #959595;
}

#nav li a:hover {
    background-color: #fafafa;
color: #005596;
font-weight: bold;
}

#nav li:hover {
    background: transparent url(images/down_arrow2.png) no-repeat scroll center bottom;
    margin: 0;
}


#active a:link, #active a:visited,#active a:hover
{
/* border: 1px solid #333; */
background-color: #fafafa;
color: #005596; 
font-weight:bold;
}



</style>
```

HTML

```
<ul id="nav">
<li id="active"><a href="home.php">Home</a></li>
<li><a href="photos.php">Photos</a></li>
<li><a href="videos.php">Videos</a></li>

<li><a href="add.php">Add a Restaurant</a></li>
<li><a href="delete.php">Delete a Restaurant</a></li>
<li><a href="logout.php">Logout</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a class name instead if an id:

```
<li class="active"><a href="home.php">Home</a></li>
```

Then you can do:

```
#nav li.active {
  background: transparent url(images/down_arrow2.png) no-repeat scroll center bottom;
  margin: 0;
}
```

Comment: If it worked then you should mark this as the correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

Just add a background image to css.

```
#active a:link, #active a:visited,#active a:hover
{
/* border: 1px solid #333; */
background-color: #fafafa;
color: #005596; 
font-weight:bold;
background: transparent url(images/down_arrow2.png) no-repeat center bottom;
    margin: 0;
}
```

Comment: I tried that it adds it in the middle of the text .I want it belwo the shadow